# installer freeze during installation Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, 19.10

I've been trying to replace my current Windows 7 installation with Ubuntu 19.10. My computer is a sony Vaio series E with AMD. I've Downloaded the software Rufus, and burned the ISO onto the USB.

When I boot from my USB. I choose "Install Ubuntu" from the menu. And then select my language in the installer. It is from this point on, it gets problematic.  when I  connected to my WIFI, it connects successfully, and when I reached to update and software the installer it freezes and nothing happened

Can someone please help me I'm new to the Linux world and barely have knowledge in this system I have been stuck in this problem for days. I have tried several online solutions but I think I didn't executed properly due to the lack of my knowledge in this system can someone guide me please

Thank you :-)

Comment: helppppppppppppppppppp

Comment: Before installation, just after BIOS disappears and language selection appears, hit ESC to hide language settings and hit F6 - Other options. There check **Nomodeset**  option, hit ESC and try to boot in Try Ubuntu without installing to check if everything works there.

Comment: I think this is a RAM issue.

Comment: @Gryu yes it's working, but after I select install ubuntu from the desktop icon same thing happened it freezes during installation

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this usually happens on systems with limited RAM. It helps to choose "install Ubuntu" immediately instead of "try Ubuntu without installing."

To avoid this problem altogether, you can use a [netboot image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) or ["minimal CD"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) instead of the "live" image. The netboot iso is called "mini.iso" and uses a text (ncurses?) based installer. The file is only 76MB so it downloads quickly and the text based installer uses very little RAM.

**First, download the "mini.iso."**

- [Click here to download the 18.04 (amd64) mini.iso file.](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)
- [Click here for other architectures.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/)

**Next,** use the mini.iso to create a bootable disk or USB device (probably use the same method you used before).

**Finally,** boot up the iso and follow the instructions. When you get to the "software selection" section, make sure the Ubuntu desktop package is selected. Also, check to see if the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package is available and if not, install this package after installing the system for all the audio and video codecs you might need.

---

Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> and your arrow keys to navigate the installer use the  <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to select or unselect a highlighted item. Use the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to press a highlighted button (similar to most BIOS interfaces).

The installer is pretty straight forward. You may need to create a partition. Make sure you select the *type* as **ext4** and set the *mount point* to `/` (a single forward slash).